# innerheight not changing style on div [JS]

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make a div, take the whole inner height of a browser dynamically and it does not work
 [image: This is how the page looks]

Ignore the black, its a div over this div. I want the gray area to take over the whole screen when i enter the divs id #cars on the adressbar

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){

       getElementById("cars").style.height = window.innerHeight + " px";

        }
    };
    </script>
```

I dont think HTML and CSS are necessary to include because its something wrong with my script.

Can someone please help me? That'd be great!

EDIT: 
FYI it does not work even when I input '1000px' instead of window.innerHeight blablabla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems with your script.

Remove the extra `}` curly brace.

Change `getElementById` to `document.getElementById`.

The full code with both fixes will be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("cars").style.height = window.innerHeight + " px";
    };
</script>
```